# Spark write parquet not writing any files, only _SUCCESS

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

The application includes

```
val stats = sqlContext.sql("select id, n from myTable")

stats.write.parquet("myTable.parquet")
```

This creates dir `myTable.parquet` with no contents other than an empty `_SUCCESS` file, even that

```
stats.show  // illustration only here, original size motivates parquet use

+-----+----+
|  id |  n |
+-----+----+
|   a |  1 |
|   b |  2 |
+-----+----+

stats.printSchema 

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- n: long (nullable = true)
```

How to make `write.parquet` to write the actual contents of the dataframe ? What is missing ?

**Note** This occurs also with `saveAsTextFile`.

Comment: Are you trying to save the file to local storage?

Comment: Ever find an answer to this? We're seeing the same behavior right now.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15393

Answer (score 7):

In my case, this was happening when I was trying to save a file to my *local* filesystem instead of the file system that is accessible from the Spark cluster.

The file is written by the Spark worker nodes, not by the PySpark client, and so it should be output to a filesystem that is accessible both by the worker nodes and the client.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that you looked at the wrong directory. The default file system Spark uses is specified by the `fs.defaultFS` Hadoop configuration option. For example, if you have something like

```
<property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>file:///tmp</value>
</property>
```

in your `core-site.xml`, then Spark writes to your local file system instead of HDFS if you omit the URL scheme of the output path. Vice versa, if it's

```
<property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>hdfs://some-host:9000</value>
</property>
```

Spark writes to HDFS by default.